# grub-install failed; fatal error

Tags: 12.04, grub-efi

I'm having trouble dual-booting 12.04 alongside Windows 8. It's a self-assembled PC, so there's no OEM UEFI or anything like that (just to be safe, I checked the BIOS settings and it was set to legacy). So the problem is I boot from the live DVD, allow Ubuntu to carve out its own partitions (by selecting "install alongside Windows 8"), it proceeds to a screen where it tells me installation was successful, then a message pops up saying

```
 "Executing 'grub-install /dev/sda' failed. This is a fatal error."
```

So I chose to finish the installation without a bootloader. Before I go further, here is the return for fdisk -l:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1  1953525167   976762583+  ee  GPT
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.

Disk /dev/sdb: 60.0 GB, 60022480896 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 7297 cylinders, total 117231408 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x89e1bf3c

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *        2048    86843397    43420675    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb2        86845438   117229567    15192065    5  Extended
/dev/sdb5        86845440   100560895     6857728   83  Linux
/dev/sdb6       100562944   117229567     8333312   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

I have it set up so that /dev/sda is my storage HDD with files accessible by both Ubuntu and W8. /dev/sdb is my SSD that I want to run both OSs on. /sdb1 is my existing Windows installation, sdb5 is the currently unbootable 12.04 installation, and sdb6 is swap.

What I have tried so far is deleting the partitions and redoing the whole thing, except initiating it by running

```
ubiquity --desktop %k gtk_ui
```

in sudo. No change in behavior. I have tried running grub-install in sudo and it completes successfully. However, when rebooting it boots what I would assume to be the GRUB terminal. Obviously the GUI form is preferable. Anyway, I'm a Linux noob, so I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Try Boot-Repair --> Recommended Repair . If still not good, indicate the URL that will appear.